# *d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ng-packagr

Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.3
: 0.3.2
: 0.3.2
: 0.3.2
: 1.2.0
: 1.10.2
: 0.3.2
: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0

We are doing lazy loading for external bundle module in our application, the external bundle is created using ng-packagr.

**Source link:**

External module: [lazy-module](https://github.com/NagarajMadyastha/lazy-module)
Application: [app-consume](https://github.com/NagarajMadyastha/app-consume)

Steps to reproduce the issue.

1. Bundle the external module "lazy-module" using "npm run cd"
2. include the bundle in "app-consume" application using “npm install  dist.tgz”
3. When we run or build app-consume application, using  “ng serve “ or “ng build” it fails

[Note: Issue won't reproduce in "ng serve -aot" and "ng build -aot",  command]

If we serve the application using development server using "ng serve" command, it fails with below error message.
Error: is logged bundle.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

ERROR in ./node_modules/bundle/bundle.d.ts
Module build failed: Error: D:\consume\node_modules\bundle\bundle.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format .
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\consume\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
    at plugin.done.then (D:\consume\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Expectation:
Able to run and build the app, using with help of "ng serve" and "ng build"

Comment: I have exactly same issue. is this fixed?